# getting information from standard output ( C++ )?

Tags: c++, file, iostream

How can I read the below information from standard output?

> Fmail@yasar.com\0Tketo@keeto.com\0Tmail@lima.com\0\0

I want to have the entire information, including the `\0` characters.

With such code:

```
string s;
fstream fs("/dev/stdout", fstream::in);
fs >> s;
```

If I write `s` to a file I get this output:

> Ftest555@itap.gov.trTislam.yasar@inforcept.comTaa@test.comTbb@test.com

All `\0` and `\0\0` are lost.

How can I do that?

Comment: What do you mean you want to read data from stdout? stdout is an output device. Do you mean stdin by chance? Or are you trying to pipe the output of another command into your program?

Comment: are you sure they are lost? maybe they do not display

Comment: no i mean exactly stdout. it is about qmail. And @AlessandroPezzato i wrote all info to the file, if they were not lost, should show when i open file ? or maybe you right. actually it is a qmail-queue wrapper.

Comment: If you are watching output with a terminal, it does not show '\0'. Try to pipe output to hexdump, it will show you "invisible" null character: echo -e "foo\0bar\0xxx" | hexdump -C

Answer (score 1):

This is just a matter of *processing* the output correctly in your shell.

Imagine this:

```
cat file_with_nulls
```

This will recklessly print the content of `file_with_nulls` to the console, and of course the console may not be equipped to display non-printable characters. However, the following works:

```
cat file_with_nulls > otherfile
```

This will create a perfect copy of `file_with_nulls`.

The same works with your program. You can write anything you want to the standard output. But don't expect your terminal or console to do anything useful with it! Rather, redirect the output to a file and all is well:

```
./myprog > output.bin
```

Note that the C string operations don't usually work with null bytes, so in C you should use `fwrite()`. In C++, strings can contain any character, so `std::cout << str;` always works. However, constructing an `std::string` from a C character array stops at the null byte, so you have to use a different constructor:

```
char cstr[] = { 'H', 'e', 0, 'l', 'l', 'o', 0 };

std::string s1(cstr);  // wrong, gives you "He"
std::string s2(cstr, sizeof(cstr));  // correct
```

Answer (score 1):

just specify binary mode:

```
std::string result;
std::fstream fs( "/dev/stdout", std::fstream::in|std::fstream::binary );
while ( !fs.eof() ) {
  std::string b;
  fs >> b;
  result += b;
}
fs.close();
```

I test it with file created by:

```
std::fstream out( "C:\\tmp\\test1.txt", std::fstream::out );
out.write( "aaa\n\0\0bbb\0ccc", 13 );
out.close();
```

But then you'll have to access data with iterators (result.begin(), result.end()) because c_str() call will truncate on '\0'